# how to have more log in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, logging

I am having this error

```
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I remember reading in some web about configuring tomcat to show more detailed info about this "previous errors"

Anyone knows how this is?

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look at [Tomcat's documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_(default))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use log4j.  Below is a simple example of logging.properties located in WEB-INF/classes:

```
# Log4j logging (also required log4j.jar to be in classpath)
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = FINEST
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

Hope it helps.